# How to pass env variable to VSCode contrib that runs in browser?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like read environment variables from within a contribution that runs in browser.

process.env['...'] does not work as browser doesnt have Node.

What is the recommended way to pass environment variable to contrib that runs in browser?

Thanks!

Comment: add the env vars as javascript strings to the HTML code